# Change Current View Without Extra Click to Ribbon List Tab (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: list-view, ribbon

In sharepoint 2007, when you were looking at a list there was already a default drop down box to change the list view.

[image: Sharepoint 2007 View Selection]

Now that we have upgraded to Sharepoint 2010, we have noticed that this drop down box is hidden in the ribbon control "List" tab which you have to click then you can select the drop down box value.

[image: Sharepoint 2010 First Click to View Selection]
[image: Sharepoint 2010 Second Click to View Selection]

Is there a way to add the drop down box to the default view in Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the first thing my business users noticed when switching too.

If you have a breadcrumb, you can click on the default view (eg: My Site > Tasks > My tasks, click on My Tasks for a view list dropdown).

There are also third party list filter web parts you can add to your page to add the view too - although it is not there by default.

As an aside, SP2010 now uses AJAX to change the list view, so if you have a page with multiple list view webparts, you won't lose context data since the page had loaded.  In SP2010 the whole page refreshed and any filtering or client-side customisation was reset.

Comment: +1 - Your first solution did it.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Selector is already there:
[image]